# Simple game development in node.js and socket.io and jquery with users turn

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am developing a game in node.js and socket.io and jquery.At the main time two users logging to the site with different location and different browser. When the first user is login to play game then a message should come "Your Turn " and he will play 30 sec. in his turn. After 30 sec. the turn goes to second user who is logged in with different location "Your turn " after the completion of 30 sec. of second user the turn goes to first user and this process will continue .

This is my app.js in node.js

```
 var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , http = require('http')
    , server = http.createServer(app)
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    server.listen(8080);
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
   var users = {};

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('addUser', function(user){
    socket.user = user;
    users[user] = user;
    socket.emit('updateUser',
    socket.user + ' has connected to this game');
    });
    socket.on('playGame1', function(data){
    io.sockets.emit('update',  data);
    });
    });
```

And this is my index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game Development In Node.js</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        //var left = {'left': '-=100'};
        socket.on('connect', function(){    
            socket.emit('addUser', prompt('Please Enter your username'));
        });

        socket.on('update',function (data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#arrow').css('left',data.left);
            $('#arrow').css('top',data.top);
            if(data.top == 50){
                alert("you won");
            }
        });

        socket.on('updateUser', function(user){         
            $('#displayUser').append('<b>'+ user +'</b>');  
        });

    //  var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
                    //          $('#loadPage').load( alert('Your Turn') );
                    //      }, 20000);


            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                    if(e.which == 37){
                        $('#arrow').css({'left': '-=100'});
                    }
                    if(e.which == 38){
                        $('#arrow').css({ 'top': '-=100' });
                    }
                    if(e.which == 39){
                        $('#arrow').css({ 'left': '+=100' });
                    }
                    if(e.which == 40){
                        $('#arrow').css({ 'top': '+=100' });                        
                    }
                    //e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)

                    var data = {left:$('#arrow').position().left,top:$('#arrow').position().top};
                                socket.emit('playGame1', data);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #arrowContainer{
                height: 500px;
                width: 500px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                margin: 0px auto;
                padding: 0px;
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #arrow{
                height: 10px;
                width: 10px;
                margin: 0px auto;
                padding: 0px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 250px;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
            #displayUser{
                float: none;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 500px;
                height: auto;
            }
            #result{
                height: 10px;
                width: 10px;
                margin: 0px auto;
                padding: 0px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="loadPage">
        <div id="displayUser"></div>
        <div id="arrowContainer">
            <div id="result">+</div>
            <div id="arrow">*</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us your code you have tried so far.

Comment: Please edit your question and place your code with proper formatting rather than adding code in comment.

Comment: Please some one help me ?

Comment: You don't get an answer because it is unclear what kind of help you need. You explained what you want to do, but not why you can't do it. Do you need to know how to use timers? Do you need to know how to implement a state machine? Or is it something different? We can not see into your head. You need to tell us what you need to know.

Comment: actually when i am setting the setInterval then the call goes same time to the both users and i want that first call goes to the first user who is loggedin first and after a time interval like 20sec the call goes to second user.

Comment: I want to know how to send the call at a specific time interval to the both users.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is going to need to do more of the work here. At a minimum, it can let the first player to join know that they are the starting player. I did this in a game called Cake Rush. The first player in the game was responsible for generating the first target. This signal is sent when the user joins the room.
Here's some sample code:

```
socket.on('joinRoom', function (data) {
  // find the room being requested
  var room = _.find(rooms, {id: data.roomId});

  // verify that player can join room:
  // room must exist and have less than 4 players
  if (!room || room.playerIds.length >= 4) {
    // send refusal
    socket.emit('connectionRefused');
    return;
  }
  var shouldGenerateFirstCake;
  if (room.playerIds.length === 0){
    shouldGenerateFirstCake = true
  }

  // register player with room
  room.playerIds.push(socket.id);
  socket.join(room.id);

  // send verification that room was joined to the player with room id
  socket.emit('roomJoined', {roomId: room.id, shouldGenerateFirstCake: shouldGenerateFirstCake});
});
```

Once you know who goes first, you should be able to synchronize the timers through one of a few means: a) timer on the server (this may be harder on server performances), b) timer on player whose turn it is automatically fires a socket event to the other player passing control, c) both players have independent timers (this is likely to be a bad idea that leads to race conditions and other issues). I'd probably try option b first.

Here's a link to the rest of the my server code: https://github.com/azurelogic/CakeRush/blob/master/controllers/cakerush.js